# C# how do I pass optional parameters as a collection?

Tags: c#, parameter-passing

Assuming I have 3rd party `MethodA(type1 paramName1 = null, type2 paramName2 = null,...., nonNullAbleSuchAsInt paramName10 = 123)`.

And I want do the following by calling the same MethodA using the provided data given by the user. User may give me data for paramName2 and paramName4, or some other permutations such as [paramName2, paramName3, paramName5, paramName7] and etc.

```
if(user gives me data for paramName2 and nothing else)
{
  MethodA(paramName2=userData2)
}
else if(user give me data for paramName2, paramName3, and nothing else)
{
  MethodA(paramName2=userData2, paramName3=userData3)
}
else if(user give me data for paramName2, paramName4, and nothing else)
{
  MethodA(paramName2=userData2, paramName4=userData4)
}
else if(user give me data for paramName2, paramName3, paramName4, and nothing else)
{
  MethodA(paramName2=userData2, paramName3=userData3, paramName4=userData4)
}
... repeat for all permutations.
```

But, that's so many duplicated code.

I want to do the following. How do I do it?

```
MagicStorage<MethodA_Declaration> magicArgs = new MagicStorage<MethodA_Declaration>();

if(user gives me data for paramName1)
{
  magicArgs.Add(paramName1, userData1);
}

if(user gives me data for paramName2)
{
  magicArgs.Add(paramName2, userData2);
}

... repeat

if(user gives me data for paramName10)
{
  magicArgs.Add(paramName10, userData10);
}

MethodA(magicArgs);
```

And if I made a mistake like `userData10` is not the same type needed by `paramName10`, I get editor and compiler error.

Is this possible? I don't want to make a method call for all the permutations of user input data. There would be too much code to manage.

Comment: How are you reading the parameters from the user?

Comment: @dcg, could be a message that contains the necessary data. Could be data that I can derive from the user data.

Comment: I would wrap the parameters in a model and just pass the model object in. Parse them internally.

Comment: @DetectivePikachu, MethodA is 3rd party, I cannot change it.

Comment: In that case I would make a factory for MethodA which can take in the parameter model object and output a MethodA. You'd still have to handle these cases in the factory but at least you wouldnt have to do it everywhere you use MethodA

Comment: @BoBoDev You can read each parameter to your own variables and then make the call. Initize them all with `null`.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is here, `MethodA` takes *nullable parameters*, just give it null, you don`t need ifs

Comment: @TheGeneral oh thats actually a good point. Create all the parameters and set to null, then pass them all in after assigning the ones you use.

Comment: @TheGeneral @dcg, I was too lazy and copy and past, but, the type can be something like `int`, I will update the question.

Comment: @BoBoDev Whichever the type is, you can initialize with `default()` (e.g. `default(int)`, `default(MyClass)`), so after you've read the data from the user into your variables, you just call `MethodA`.

Comment: `int` or `int?`? If its non-nullable `int`, there has to be a default value in the method signature, just initialize the parameter to that instead of null. If `int?` you can pass in null.

Comment: @DetectivePikachu, it is `nonNullAbleSuchAsInt` as the updated question passed in default of 123.

Comment: If its non-nullable such as int, then just pass in the default value. If you don't supply it, its supplying it by default.

Comment: @BoBoDev any reason why you did not use a `class` with properties and default values set in that object and use that as a single unique parameter ? or you simply did not think about it ?

Comment: @Franck it is a 3rd party Method, I don't have control over it. But, it is a good question to the 3rd party vendor.

Comment: You can still use @Franck 's suggestion and write a wrapper method that takes in an instance of a class and then calls the 3rd party method, like TheGeneral's answer. But it does require that you know the default values for optional arguments.

Comment: @Rufus, hardcoding the default value on my side is fragile because I don't know when the vender will change 123 to 456. If update the software, it takes extra care to make sure they still match.

Comment: Updates always take extra care to make sure everything still works right. You absolutely must regression test when you update libraries, even if the release notes dont indicate breaking changes. Trust, but verify.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of the now-defaced https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58755320/how-do-i-pass-optional-parameters-as-an-array#comment103799285_58755320

Comment: How are you getting information from the user? In other words, how do you store the mapping of "parameterName" and "parameterValue"? Is it a `Dictionary<string, object>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use reflection to call the method with an ordered array of parameters, where the user specified values are used where possible and `Type.Missing` used where no value was specified:

```
public static object InvokeWithOrderedParameters(object instance, string methodName,
    IDictionary<string, object> namedParameters)
{
    // Get the method to invoke
    var method = instance.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);

    // Get an array of ordered parameter values based on the specified named 
    // parameters, with a default value of "Type.Missing" for any missing names 
    var orderedParams = method.GetParameters().Select(param =>
    {
        object value;

        // Set the value from our dictionary, or if that fails use "Type.Missing"
        if (!namedParameters.TryGetValue(param.Name, out value))
        {
            value = Type.Missing;
        }

        return value;
    }).ToArray();

    // Invoke the method with the ordered parameters and return the value
    return method.Invoke(instance, orderedParams);
}
```

With this method, we can pass the instance of our type, the name of the method to invoke, and a `Dictionary<string, object>` of named parameters and their values, and it will return the result of calling that method with the parameters that we specified.

As an example, here's a method that has default values for all it's parameters:

```
public class ThirdParty
{
    public string MethodA(string arg1 = "defaultArg1", string arg2 = "defaultArg2",
        string arg3 = "defaultArg3")
    {
        return $"{arg1}, {arg2}, {arg3}";
    }
}
```

And we can use our reflection method to call it with as many named parameters as we like. Below I'm just giving a value for the second parameter:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var namedParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        {"arg2", "custom Arg 2 value"}
    };

    var instance = new ThirdParty();
    var result = InvokeWithOrderedParameters(instance, "MethodA", namedParameters);

    Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

As you can see, the value we specified was passed, and the default values were used where we didn't specify anything:

[image]

Comment: This is something closer to what I was trying to do, so, I marked as solution. Doesn't shows compiler error though, but, this is much less error prone in terms of default value changes. I probably would need some kind of param name validation performed once when app starts.

Comment: Yes, it needs validation on the method name, and that instance isn't null, etc. Reflection isn't the most friendly thing to use, but it does avoid all the `if` statements, and doesn't require that you know any default values.

Answer (score 3):

Given

```
MethodA(type1 paramName1 = null, type2 paramName2 = null, int paramName10 = 132).
```

Usage

```
public class data
{
    public type1 ParamName1 {get;set;}
    public type2 paramName2 {get;set;}
    // initalize with what ever default the method takes as optional
    public int paramName10 {get;set;} = 123; 
}

...

// pass in all paramaters, dont both about ifs
// we can do this, because you have already figured out the defaults
// from the signature 
MethodA(data.ParamName1, data.paramName2, data.paramName10);
```

Comment: This is hacky because the 3rd party vender can change 123 to 456. I would have to be very careful updating the 3rd party component and making sure all those hardcoded values still match every single time I update.

Comment: Anyway, I am marking this as answer because there doesn't seem to be other choices without inflating the lines of code. I probably would have to make a comment on the code to make sure I cannot upgrade the 3rd party component blindly because default values can become out of sync. And probably asking 3rd party to expose the default value publicly would be something more do able.

Comment: @BoBoDev yeah if you can talk to the author, see if you can just pass in 1 parameter class, not much more you can do here

Answer (score 0):

You can make it somewhat more readable using the [switch support for pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#when-clauses-in-case-expressions).

And of course you can replace any switch with a Dictionary and a loop, as long as the value has place for a function delegate. Of course in this case, the Key might need to have a delegate too.

Those would make the code more readable, but can not avoid the write work.

Beyond that, there is only moving the resolution of the function calls out of compile time and into runtime. A step I am not a friend off and thus have little experience in.

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like

```
int param1 = default(int);
double param2 = default(double);
MyClass param3 = default(MyClass);
 ....
int param10 = 123;
ReadUserData(out param1, out param2, out param3, ..., out param10)
```

Then call `MethodA`:

```
MethodA(param1, param2, param3, ..., param10)
```

NOTE: Starting with C# 7.0 (I think) when using `out` parameters there is a sugar that let you declare the variables with the method call (so you don't have to declare them one by one), for example, the call to `ReadUserData` can be done as:

```
ReadUserData(out int param1, out double param2, out MyClass param3, ..., out int param10)
```

Comment: Just make sure you check the method signature to make sure it is using the default value when not supplied, they could be using any value if its not supplied. if 0 is a valid input they might make the default value when not supplied -1 for example

Comment: You're right, you should know what's the default value in case it isn't given by the user

Comment: I am not sure how this works because the default value for param10 is 123, which is not exposed to me publicly. I may be able to hack it by reading the metadata and hardcode the 123 myself, but, I can't be sure when will the 3rd party vendor change its default value.

Comment: That's another thing, if this is an API it should be clear what are the defaults

Comment: You should at least be able to see the method signature in the metadata

Comment: Like I said above, it is hacky to hardcode 123 on my end when 3rd party can change it.

Comment: If the 3rd party changes it, it would be in a new version. Just dont upgrade until you've verified the defaults haven't changed. You're calling methods, not making api calls, so they shouldnt be able to change anything out from under you like that.

Comment: I guess the suggestion is to not upgrade the 3rd party component because they sux, until I fully validated the API didn't change.

Comment: Anyway, I am marking this as answer because there doesn't seem to be other choices without inflating the lines of code. I probably would have to make a comment on the code to make sure I cannot upgrade the 3rd party component blindly because default values can become out of sync. And probably asking 3rd party to expose the default value publicly would be something more do able.

Oops, I can only mark one as answer. Since the other one is more clear, I use the other one instead.